# Proving strict positivity of a function of two variables with a constraint

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Suppose I have a smooth function of two variables, $f(x,y)$ defined on $U \subset \mathbb{R}^{2}$. I also impose a simple condition, say that $y<x/2$, for all $x$ and $y$.

I would like to investigate simple properties of $f(x,y)$ subject to this condition. Precisely, I suspect that $f(x,y)>0$ on  a certain subset of $U$. How could I prove / disprove this, in general terms?

To me, it looks like a setup from some optimisation theory, but I am not finding min/max values.

I would be grateful if someone could point out a general "prescription", it it exists, to approach such a problem, or direct me to relevant part of mathematics that deals with such topics? Or is this something that really has to be dealt on a case-by-case basis?

Comment: Do you mean that $U \subset \{(x, y)^T \in \mathbb{R}^2 : y < \frac{x}{2}\}$? Maybe I misunderstood but what if $f(x,y) = -1$?

Comment: Yes indeed, that is my definition of $U$. I assume $f(x,y)$ to be non constant. @echzhen

Comment: $f(x,y) = -x^2$?

Comment: For example. This is a specific function I am interested in. Take $f(x,y) = x \left(\cos \pi y/x \right) \left(1-\cos \pi y/x \right) - \sin \pi y /x$. For the set $U$ with $x>5$, $y>2$, and $y<x/2$ it seems  $f(x,y)$ is positive, but how would one show this? @echzhen

Comment: Ah, sorry I thought you want to prove it for all smooth functions, which doesn't make sense. You can find one point where the function is positive and using continuity your function is positive in neighborhood.

Comment: Yes, exactly  -  what I wanted to ask is, if I have a smooth function $f(x,y)$, how does one generally go about inspecting if its positive or negative on some (sub)set of the plane? And how does this method change if one adds a constraint? @echzhen

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36237/discussion-between-echzhen-and-alex).